# How to do projection from world coordinates to pixel coordinates?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, projection, open3d

i created point clouds from a sequence of RGBD frames by using the reconstruction system of Open3d and I picked 8 points in point clouds by drawing a 3dbb(i have their positions)
now I want to project these points from world coordinates to pixel coordinates to find the position of each point in each RGB frames and I have all camera parameters such as camera intrinsic matrix, pose matrices(extrinsic matrices=rotation and translation matrices) but I do not know what is the best way to do that? i know the basics of 3d to 2d projection but I could not find any specific script for that and I am not good at programming to write its program
can someone help me with that?
i appreciate any help
thanks

Comment: opencv has a projectPoints function: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga1019495a2c8d1743ed5cc23fa0daff8c

Comment: @Micka thank you, do i need to transform points from world frame to camera's frame first? is there any function for that?

Comment: as you can read in the link, objectPoints are in world coordinates. You have to provide rvec and tvec, which are the extrinsic camera parameters, as well as the intrinsncs and the distortion coefficients of the camea. The transformation from world to camera coordinates and to image plabe is performed by the function.

Comment: great, thank you so much

Comment: @Micka i open another question related to the output of the projectPoints() , i would be grateful if you could see it and help me with that,thanks   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65248761/output-of-projectpoints-function