# Output of projectPoints() function

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, projection

i used `projectPoints()` function of OpenCV to do projection from world coordinates to pixel coordinates, the output image points are vector point2f, how can I extract the x,y coordinates from imagePoints?
seconde question, some of the imagePoints are negative like below: I just project 2 points and these are the results
[[[-37.95361728 316.5438248 ]]
[[204.89090594 316.5144533 ]]]
if I show these coordinates without the negative sign on the image it is correct
first why i get a negative sign and how can i solve these issues?
i appreciate any help, thanks
this is my  code :

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np

objectPoints = np.array([[ -0.8565132125748637 , 0.18200966481269648 , 0.9606457931958912 ],[-0.2565132125748638 , 0.18200966481269648 , 0.9606457931958912]] , np.float)
tvec = np.matrix([[-0.00016514 ],[ 0.00523247 ], [-0.00371881]])
rvec = np.matrix([[0.99987256 , -0.00294761 , -0.01569025],[0.00261951 , 0.99977833  , -0.02089080],[0.01574835 , 0.02084704 , 0.99965864]])
cameraMatrix = np.matrix([[ 381.58892822265625 , 0 , 313.5216979980469 ],[ 0, 381.1356201171875 , 250.1746826171875],[ 0 , 0 , 1 ]])
distCoeffs = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0], np.float)

imagePoints, jacobian   =   cv2.projectPoints(  objectPoints, rvec, tvec, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs  )
print(imagePoints)
```

Comment: negative sign means your point is projected outside of your image area. If you get the right image point when inverting the sign this probably means your rvec and tvec are wrong/inverted.

Comment: @Micka thanks, do you know how can I extract the x,y coordinates from imagePoints (vector point2f)?

Comment: it's just the 2 values, first is x, second is y. I don't know the Python syntax. In C++ it would be imagePoints[i][0] for x coordinate of point i and imagePoints[i][1] for y coordinate.

Comment: @Micka it is not like that, as you can see in my question, there is not any (,) between x,y coordinates so by this way I get the first  imagePoints again, not separated one

Comment: `[-37.95361728 316.5438248 ]` is two values, x and y. there's a space between them. do not be confused because you don't see a comma. this is just how np.arrays are printed. use `print(repr(...))` to see the other type of string representation.